# More than one JSON formats for same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

I'm working on Rails 5 api for SPA. I have a the model:

```
class Apartment < ApplicationRecord
end
```

and their serializer:

```
class ApartmentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :price, :name, :detail # too many other attributes
end
```

In the app I need to list all apartments showing a thumbnail, price and name for each apartment (`/aparetments`) and I also need to show all data for a specific apartment (`/aparetments/id`).
Apartment list is too long so I just want to use the necessary data (thumbnail, price and name). I won't use the same json for both actions. 
I thought create a helper:

```
ApartmentJsonHelper.json_list(@apartments) # should return [{thumbnail: "some_1/url.jpg", price:"999999", name: "A name 1"}, {thumbnail: "some_2/url.jpg", price:"999999", name: "A name 2"}, ...]

ApartmentJsonHelper.show(@apartment_model) # Should return {id:"1", price:"999999", name: "A name 1", detail: "A long detail..." # too many other attributes}
```

What do you think about this approach? What is "the rails way" to do it?

Comment: Or you could specify serializer in your `render` calls. This seems the right way to me.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev what do you mean by "specify serializer"? suggest declare several serializer classes for the same model?

Comment: Yep, different serializers for different needs. Isn't that exactly what you need?

Comment: You can post the your answer with some sample code if you want.